# How to safely open regular files without denial-of-service vulnerability?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

The flag `O_DIRECTORY` can be used with the syscalls `open(2)` and `openat(2)` to avoid denial-of-service vulnerabilities when opening directories. However: How can I avoid the same kind of race conditions for *regular files*?

Some background information: I am trying to develop some kind of backup tool. The programs walks over a directory tree, reads all regular files and only stats other files. If I first call `fstatat(2)` for each directory entry, test the result for regular files and open them with `openat(2)`, then there is a race condition between the syscalls. An attacker could replace the regular file with a FIFO, and my program would hang on the FIFO.

How can I avoid this race condition? For directories, there is `O_DIRECTORY`, for symbolic links, `O_PATH` can be used. However, I have found no solution for regular files. I only need a solution that works on recent Linux versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your only concern is fifos, `O_NONBLOCK` will prevent blocking and allow you to open a fifo even if it has a no writers (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html for where this is specified). However, there are also a few other concerns:

- Device nodes
- Fake files in Linux `/proc` with bad properties
- ...

Since these normally can't be created in arbitrary locations by non-root users, `O_NOFOLLOW` should be sufficient to avoid following symlinks to them.

With that said, on modern Linux there is an *even safer* solution: perform the initial `open` with `O_PATH|O_NOFOLLOW`, then perform `stat` on `/proc/self/fd/%d` to check the file type. You can then open `/proc/self/fd/%d` and be completely certain it corresponds to the same file you just `stat`'d.

Note that on sufficiently new Linux, you don't need to use `/proc/self/fd/%d` to reach the file to which you obtained an inode handle with `O_PATH`. You can use `fstat` and `openat` on it directly to "stat" it and get a descriptor to a real open file description, respectively. However `O_PATH` file descriptors had a lot of broken/unimplemented corner cases like this in the range of late 2.6.x (when they were first added) to 3.8 or so, and I find the `/proc` method the most reliable. Of course you could always try the direct method and fallback to `/proc` if it fails.

Comment: No matter what you open, if you set O_NONBLOCK, the system call will either return a valid file descriptor, or a -1 with errno set to E_WOULDBLOCK. (Or something like permission denied and so on). But in no case will it block.

Comment: I'm not sure that's 100% true with device nodes; badly behaved devices might be able to initiate a non-interruptable sleep during open. And of course ordinary files can always do that during open, e.g. if they're on a scratched optical disk or nfs mount with connectivity problems. :-(

Comment: Agree. But these are issues that userspace software just shouldn't attempt to handle. If you want to protect your program against bad hardware, you end up asking "how do i handle power outages beyond what SIGPWR allows me". I'd draw the line at "i promise my program works correctly as long as the OS does what it's specified to do".

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Sadly, exhibiting sane behavior on scratched CDs/DVDs is a practical, real-world requirement for media player applications, and an area in which most fail horribly. If the whole UI freezes up and fails to even repaint or anything as soon as you hit a scratch, that's horrible user experience. The only "fix" I know is using lots of threads for reading, cancelling and detaching ones that seem stuck, and letting them eventually die after the hardware finishes retrying for 5 minutes or whatever.

Comment: I guess you're right. Still, in a perfect world, i think the correct way to handle this is to set the retry count to 1 or 2 in the driver/device firmware, and have the driver return -1 if it can't read the sector within a second or so. But i guess there's many more people who are able to use a framework to create a GUI than there are people who can fiddle with device drivers and firmware. Seems i'll have to realize, some day, that the world just isn't perfect :-/

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Having a global setting at the driver level is very problematic. Consider one application may be trying to play a movie while another may be trying to recover as much information as possible off a damaged disc. Media player developers would love a configurable read timeout on a per-open-file level, but in any case, this is getting fairly off-topic... :-)

Comment: I am using Linux 3.11. However, `openat(fd, "", ...)` doesn't work if `fd` was created with `open(..., O_PATH)`. But `fstatat(fd, "", ..., AT_EMPTY_PATH)` works.

Comment: Yes, apparently we're still missing a way to pass the equivalent of `AT_EMPTY_PATH` to `openat`. I don't think you can't just omit it because that case seems to be required to fail as part of the spec, at least if `""` qualifies as a "relative path".

Answer (score 2):

Open with O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK, check that the result isn't -1, then do an fstat() on the resulting file descriptor and compare st_mode (and possibly st_dev and st_ino) with what you expected.

Remember to set the AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW flag on your fstatat.